# How to create multi-key index in Cosmos DB with MongoAPI?

Tags: mongodb, azure-cosmosdb

Mongo provides support for multi-key index on collection. I am now migrating mongo DB to cosmos and wondering how can I get same indexing behavior in Cosmos DB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the [mongo Shell](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/mongo/), you can use [`createIndex`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/) to create a new collection with the keys you want.

For example, the following will create a collection called `my_collection` with a 3-key compound index of `(key1, key2, key3)`:

```
db.my_collection.createIndex({key1: 1, key2: 1, key3: 1})
```

If we wish to make the index unique, we would do:

```
db.my_collection.createIndex({key1: 1, key2: 1, key3: 1}, {unique: true})
```

Refer to [Indexing in the Azure Cosmos DB: MongoDB API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-indexing) for more specific details.

Comment: Thank you. Good that now they have added this in documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The indexing behavior in Cosmos DB is different as it is different implementation and uses cloud infrastructure shared with other APIs. For one, it automatically indexes every path in the document (all fields, even the ones that show up only in one doc).  Now, you can execute the same createIndex commands though in the very same way. (with exception to unique - this needs to be executed on empty collection only).

Comment: I have asked for multi-key index creation.

Comment: What issues are you seeing while trying to create them in Cosmos DB? And what tools do you use to migrate the data?

Answer (score 0):

I am using the MongoDB.Driver API in .NET Core with a CosmosDB and I am doing this:

```
var key1 = Builders<MyType>.IndexKeys.Ascending(x => x.Field1);
var key2 = Builders<MyType>.IndexKeys.Ascending(x => x.Field2);
var key3 = Builders<MyType>.IndexKeys.Ascending(x => x.Field3);
var keys = Builders<MyType>.IndexKeys.Combine(key1, key2, key3);
var options = new CreateIndexOptions { Unique = false };
var indexModel = new CreateIndexModel<MyType>(keys, options);
var indexName = myCollection.Indexes.CreateOne(indexModel, new CreateOneIndexOptions { });
```

The call seems to succeed and the indexName comes back as something that looks good, as if it got created, but when I retrieve the list of indexes again it does not appear.

I am able to add indexes containing a single field- they show up in a retrieved list, but not with a combined index like this.